# What is the interpretation of complex amplitudes in the many-worlds interpretation?

Tags: quantum-interpretations

Many (popular?) accounts of MWI seems to suggest that MWI "solves everything" (including collapse), as long as you accept the infinitely branching (and co-existing) universes, etc. But I don't fully understand it... because to reproduce the phenomena of QM you need negative or even complex probability amplitudes (for instance to explain destructive interference in the dual-slit experient). But with MWI there's by definition no longer a collapse and a Born rule (at the lowest interpretation level at least), but the appearance has to be explained. So how would MWI - for instance - explain destructive interference in the dual-slit experiments? There must be an element in addition to "just" branching because branching would (naively) lead to some amount of universes in various states and we might be able to interpret the density of various types of states as reflecting the probability amplitudes of those states in the wave function. This is easy to see, as long as the amplitudes are positive, but this is clearly not sufficient because QM requires negative/complex amplitudes to explain all phenomena.

Comment: Speculative, philosophical  topic not covered in physics